# Why does an empty `~/Movies` folder take up 273 GB?

Tags: folders

My `~/Movies` folder is empty according to both the Finder and Terminal.

[image]

I've never seen this before. In case it's relevant, this is a 2012 Mac mini running the latest version of Yosemite. It runs a few services, including file sharing, FileMaker Server, calibre, Time Machine and Plex.

Comment: what does the command line tool du show for the directory?

Comment: Try `ls -la@` and see if there's a difference?

Comment: What happens if you create a file and then delete the file from that folder? How about if you create a folder and then delete it from that folder? I'd also try opening Disk Utility and running First Aid on your Frodo drive.

Comment: Try showing hidden files. There might be a .Trashes folder or .DS_Store folder that you can't see but is taking up all that space.

Comment: @NoahL `ls -la` shows hidden files which was included in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions in the comments, I performed the following commands in the terminal:

```
~ $ cd Movies/

Movies $ du
0   .

Movies $ ls -la@
total 0
drwx------+  2 administrator  staff   68 Jun 11 13:41 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 administrator  staff  782 Jun 11 21:31 ..

Movies $ touch file

Movies $ ls -la
total 0
drwx------+  3 administrator  staff  102 Jun 12 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 administrator  staff  782 Jun 11 21:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 administrator  staff    0 Jun 12 10:20 file

Movies $ rm file

Movies $ ls -la
total 0
drwx------+  2 administrator  staff   68 Jun 12 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 administrator  staff  782 Jun 11 21:31 ..

Movies $ mkdir dir

Movies $ ls -la
total 16
drwx------+  4 administrator  staff   136 Jun 12 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 administrator  staff   782 Jun 11 21:31 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 administrator  staff  6148 Jun 12 10:20 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   2 administrator  staff    68 Jun 12 10:20 dir

Movies $ rm -r dir

Movies $ ls -la
total 16
drwx------+  3 administrator  staff   102 Jun 12 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 administrator  staff   782 Jun 11 21:31 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 administrator  staff  6148 Jun 12 10:20 .DS_Store

Movies $ du
16  .

Movies $ du -h
8.0K    .

Movies $
```

Get Info on the folder now reveals it to have 6K (for the `.DS_Store` that showed up with the folder creation, no doubt). Honestly, I didn't check the Get Info after each command, so I don't know which, if any of the above fixed it.